# Converting a NSDictionary into a NSMutableDictionary in a for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have the following code:

```
for (NSMutableDictionary *aDict in array)
{
     // do stuff
     [aDict setObject:myTitle forKey:@"title"];
}
```

My question is, if the `array` is filled with `NSDictionary` objects, will this for loop code as written automatically convert them into `NSMutableDictionary` objects?

Or do I need to do something more specific here to ensure that I don't get an `unrecognized selector sent to instance` error on `setObject:forKey:` in the loop?

Comment: No.  Simply assigning/casting a NSDictionary pointer to and NSMutableDictionary pointer will not change the type of the object.  You must use `mutableCopy` or one of the other options to create a new object.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a JSON response, perhaps? If so, there's a convenient way to get your non-mutable objects back as mutable objects.

Comment: Nope, not for JSON, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently that will give you the error you mentioned. Whilst the loop is setup with mutable dictionaries, the underlying object is still immutable. You'd need to create a new dictionary out of it. Try this

```
NSMutableArray *newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSDictionary *aDict in array)
{
     NSMutableDictionary *mutable = [aDict mutableCopy];
     // do stuff
     [mutable setObject:myTitle forKey:@"title"];
     [newArray addObject:mutable];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example! What if I am unsure of whether the array contains `NSMutableDictionary`'s or `NSDictionary`'s? I should know... but if I didn't, is there a way to check? Or does it matter with this example code you show?

Comment: You can always do a simple check by either doing `[aDict isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]` or by checking if it responds to a mutable method such as `[aDict respondsTo:@selector(setObject:forKey:)]`

Answer (score 0):

No it will not automatically convert them. You have to do that yourself. You'll definitely get the unrecognized selector sent to instance exception.